# Extending Regex test to check for whitespace and/or period as final character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am testing a string via regex.

```
const validations = /\s*P\s*\.*[O0]\.*\s+/i;
```

**handleChange**

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
    const isValid = validations.test(e.target.value);
    if (isValid) {
      triggerErr();
    } else {
      setErr("");
    }
  };
```

I am testing for a white space character at the end, but would also like the error to trigger if the final character is ".", without the whitespace.

**EX:** both "P.O. " and "P.O." will trigger the error

how can I achieve this?

Comment: You could just trim your string and check for a period at the end.

Comment: Or use `/[. ]+$/` to trigger the error.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `\s*P\s*\.*[O0]\.*\s+` matches  1 or more whitespace characters at the end of the pattern due to `\s+`

Assuming you don't want to allow mixing spaces and dots at the end, and as you already match 0+ repetitions of a dot here `[O0]\.*`  you can change the quantifier of the following `\s+` to `\s*` and assert the end of the string with `$`

**Note** that `\s` can also match a newline.

```
\s*P\s*\.*[O0]\.*\s*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rryclG/1)